# Agora Raw Audio on Android

Tags: android, agora.io

My end goal is to visualize the remote audio in a one on one call using the Agora Api.  The agora api and available examples are quite vast but I did not find a example that allows me to access the audio as it is streamed in so that I can then get the samples max amplitude and send to a visualizer.The byte array would do just fine.
I have looked through the examples provide at https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples, which seemed promising but I have not been able to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

(Within the API_Example on Github, I have attempted to implement ProcessRawData and AudioRecordService)

Update: The APIExample allows me to grab the raw data as it flows through and that is what I am looking for. The issue arises when I try to duplicate the "ProcessRawData" class in a new project. The call back for the audio observer is never called. I have gone through my code and it matches everything in the example. The only thing I can think of is that the method to import the "lib-raw-data" folder was incorrect. I simply copied the entrire folder 'lib-raw-data' from the example api project and into my own. I then added the library directory to the gradle.settings file as well as the gradle(app) file. Outisde of that, I simply made sure the code matches the example provided.

Below is the most basic form of my application with the imported library "lib-raw-data" as described. I have no errors within Android Studio so I don't know where to look. The example in the github above works, but the same code below does not.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SessionVideoCall videoCall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initVideoCall();
}




private void initVideoCall(){
    videoCall = new SessionVideoCall(this);
    videoCall.setChannelName(#CHANNEL_NAME);
    videoCall.attachView();
    videoCall.startCall();
}
```

}

SessionVideoCall.java

```
public class SessionVideoCall implements MediaDataAudioObserver {

private Handler handler;
private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID = 44;
private static final String[] REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

private final Activity ACTIVITTY;

private MediaDataObserverPlugin mediaDataObserverPlugin;

private String channelName;
private FrameLayout mLocalContainer;
private FrameLayout mRemoteContainer;
private VideoCanvas mLocalVideo;
private VideoCanvas mRemoteVideo;
private Timer timer;

boolean isVisualizerAttached = true;

public static RtcEngine engine;

// set up engine
public SessionVideoCall(Activity activity){
    this.ACTIVITTY = activity;
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

// set channel name
public void setChannelName(String channelName){
    this.channelName = channelName;
}

public void attachView(){
    mLocalContainer = ACTIVITTY.findViewById(R.id.local_video_view_container);
    mRemoteContainer = ACTIVITTY.findViewById(R.id.remote_video_view_container);
}



// start call
public void startCall(){
    if(hasPermissions())
        initEngineAndJoinChannel();
}

// end call

public void endCall(){
    removeFromParent(mLocalVideo);
    mLocalVideo = null;
    removeFromParent(mRemoteVideo);
    mRemoteVideo = null;

    if (mediaDataObserverPlugin != null) {
        mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeAudioObserver(this);
        mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeAllBuffer();
    }
    MediaPreProcessing.releasePoint();
    leaveChannel();
}


private void initEngineAndJoinChannel() {
    initializeEngine();
    setupObserver();
    setupAudioConfig();
    setupVideoConfig();
    setupLocalVideo();
    joinChannel();
}


private void initializeEngine() {
    try {
        engine = RtcEngine.create(ACTIVITTY.getApplicationContext(), ACTIVITTY.getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcEventHandler);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        throw new RuntimeException("NEED TO check rtc sdk init fatal error\n" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}

private void setupObserver(){
    mediaDataObserverPlugin = MediaDataObserverPlugin.the();
    MediaPreProcessing.setCallback(mediaDataObserverPlugin);
    MediaPreProcessing.setAudioPlayByteBuffer(mediaDataObserverPlugin.byteBufferAudioPlay);
    mediaDataObserverPlugin.addAudioObserver(this);
}


private void setupAudioConfig(){
    engine.setChannelProfile(Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_LIVE_BROADCASTING);
    engine.setClientRole(IRtcEngineEventHandler.ClientRole.CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER);


    engine.setDefaultAudioRoutetoSpeakerphone(false);
    engine.setEnableSpeakerphone(false);

    engine.setPlaybackAudioFrameParameters(4000, 1, RAW_AUDIO_FRAME_OP_MODE_READ_ONLY, 1024);

}


private void setupVideoConfig() {
    engine.enableVideo();

    engine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration(
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.VD_640x360,
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_15,
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.STANDARD_BITRATE,
            VideoEncoderConfiguration.ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_PORTRAIT));
}



private void setupLocalVideo() {
    SurfaceView view = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(ACTIVITTY);
    view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
    mLocalContainer.addView(view);
    mLocalVideo = new VideoCanvas(view, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, 0);
    engine.setupLocalVideo(mLocalVideo);
}

private void joinChannel() {
    String token = ACTIVITTY.getString(R.string.agora_access_token);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(token) || TextUtils.equals(token, "#YOUR ACCESS TOKEN#")) {
        token = null; // default, no token
    }
    engine.joinChannel(token, channelName, "Extra Optional Data", 0);

}

private void leaveChannel(){
    if (mediaDataObserverPlugin != null) {
        mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeAudioObserver(this);
        mediaDataObserverPlugin.removeAllBuffer();
    }
    MediaPreProcessing.releasePoint();
    engine.leaveChannel();
    if(timer != null)
        timer.cancel();
}

private void removeFromParent(VideoCanvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null) {
        ViewParent parent = canvas.view.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) parent;
            group.removeView(canvas.view);
            //return group;
        }
    }
    //return null;
}



private void setupRemoteVideo(int uid) {
    ViewGroup parent = mRemoteContainer;
    if (parent.indexOfChild(mLocalVideo.view) > -1) {
        parent = mLocalContainer;
    }

    if (mRemoteVideo != null) {
        return;
    }

    SurfaceView view = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(ACTIVITTY);
    view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(parent == mLocalContainer);
    parent.addView(view);
    mRemoteVideo = new VideoCanvas(view, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_HIDDEN, uid);
    // Initializes the video view of a remote user.
    engine.setupRemoteVideo(mRemoteVideo);
}



private final IRtcEngineEventHandler mRtcEventHandler = new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onJoinChannelSuccess(String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
        super.onJoinChannelSuccess(channel, uid, elapsed);
        setupTimer();
        Log.d(TAG,"onJoinChannelSuccess: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded(final int uid, int width, int height, int elapsed) {
        ACTIVITTY.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG,"First remote video decoded, uid: " + (uid & 0xFFFFFFFFL));
                setupRemoteVideo(uid);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onUserOffline(final int uid, int reason) {
        super.onUserOffline(uid, reason);
        // when remote user logs off
    }


    @Override
    public void onUserJoined(int uid, int elapsed) {
        super.onUserJoined(uid, elapsed);
        Log.i(TAG, "onUserJoined->" + uid);
        Log.d(TAG, "user has joined call: " + uid);
        handler.post(() ->
        {
            if (mediaDataObserverPlugin != null) {
                mediaDataObserverPlugin.addDecodeBuffer(uid);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoteAudioStateChanged(int uid, int state, int reason, int elapsed)
    {
        super.onRemoteAudioStateChanged(uid, state, reason, elapsed);
        Log.i(TAG, "onRemoteAudioStateChanged->" + uid + ", state->" + state + ", reason->" + reason);
    }



};

private boolean hasPermissions(){
    return (checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0]) &&
            checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1]) &&
            checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[2]) &&
            checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[3]));
}

private boolean checkSelfPermission(String permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ACTIVITTY, permission) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ACTIVITTY, REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQ_ID);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


private void setupTimer(){
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(maxAmplitude > 0)
                Log.e(TAG, "Amplitude Greater than 0: " + maxAmplitude);
        }

    },0,50);
}



@Override
public void onRecordAudioFrame(byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onRecordAudioFrame: ");
}

private int maxAmplitude = 0;
@Override
public void onPlaybackAudioFrame(byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {
    if(isVisualizerAttached) {
        short[] rawAudio = new short[data.length/2];
        ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(rawAudio);
        short amplitude = 0;
        for(short num: rawAudio){
            if(num > amplitude)
                amplitude = num;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "onPlaybackAudioFrame: Supposedly we have data -> max: " + amplitude);
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "onPlaybackAudioFrame:");
}

@Override
public void onPlaybackAudioFrameBeforeMixing(int uid, byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onPlaybackAudioFrameBeforeMixing: ");
}

@Override
public void onMixedAudioFrame(byte[] data, int audioFrameType, int samples, int bytesPerSample, int channels, int samplesPerSec, long renderTimeMs, int bufferLength) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onMixedAudioFrame: ");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Did you give/add permissions in the manifest? Because Agora does not show any runtime error when you don't give/add permissions; instead, your voice call goes blank, and the microphone and speaker buttons, if added, won't do anything. This is what I went through one day dealing with some code on GitHub by Agora (that is, it didn't look up the manifest file).

According to the Agora documentation, the following permissions are required:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered where in the API Example (provided by the github repo link above), where to interact with the remote audio data. In the CustomAudioSource class, within the AsyncTask object at the bottom of the file. Had to run on physical device to take advantage of it.

Now I am need of finding the max amplitude of the audio byte array. The formula given within this example is "lengthInByte = sampleRate/1000 × 2 × channels × audio duration (ms)"

Comment: The AudioPlayer interface within the example does not seem to play the audio. There must be a simplier way to do this.

Comment: Can you log the following values: audioData, offsetInBytes, sizeInBytes that are passed to the play method?
Is the callback onRemoteAudioStateChanged getting executed? Because, that is where the AudioPlayer is getting started without which the audio playback will not happen

Comment: Also, if there are any relevant logs you can share, that would help a lot.